# About NPM and nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, server

Is there any way to keep NPM always in running position even if I close my command prompt? I tried using start stop restart method but it does not work out. how can I get out from this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the NPM goal to launch programs that stay in background.
To do what you want you should start the node process with the following option.

```
nohup <your command here> &
```

Example:

```
nohup node server.js &
```

***nohup***: Attach the command to the process with PID 1, that means that your program will be killed only if your reboot the server, or if you kill the process yourself.

***&***: Launch the process in background, that means that you can still use your prompt.